# Error while try to remove Unicode special character in python 2.7 TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object

Tags: python, python-2.7

I try to remove Unicode special character in python 2.7 but i got error

> newr = r.translate ({ord(c): "" for c in "“”"}) TypeError: expected a
>   string or other character buffer object

here my code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
r= "“សួស្តី” – “អ្នក” – “Ok”"
newr = r.translate ({ord(c): "" for c in "“”"})
print (newr)
```

and i want remove this.

> “ ”

***PS: this is Khmer Unicode***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```py
r = "“សួស្តី” – “អ្នក” – “Ok”"
newr = r.replace("“","").replace("”","")
print (newr)
```

or

```py
r = "“សួស្តី” – “អ្នក” – “Ok”"
newr = ''.join(x for x in r if x != '”' and x != '“')
print (newr)
```

**Edit: you edited your question so my answer might not be valid anymore, but it still seems to work for me**

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2.7, the str type is a byte string and has no notion of unicode characters. Simply some byte sequence may happen to be utf-8 encoded unicode characters. If you want to process unicode characters, you must decode the byte string into a unicode one with `ur = r.decode('utf-8')`.

Moreover, the `translate` method has different syntax when called on a byte string and on a unicode one. Your code use the unicode syntax but is applied to a byte string, hence the error.

What is want is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
r= "“សួស្តី” – “អ្នក” – “Ok”"

newr = r.decode('utf-8').translate ({ord(c): None for c in u"“”"})
print (newr)      # or print(newr.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: when I try to apply it into my project I got the error "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 85-90: ordinal not in range(128)" and my data is unicode string type.

Comment: @SidaraKEO: In my code only the `print(newr)` could raise that error, and the fix would be `print(newr.encode('utf-8'))`. You should ask a new question if it is something different.